# How to detect hardware keyboard in class of UIInputViewController?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I have an app with a custom keyboard extension, I want to show a prediction view whenever Hardware (Bluetooth) keyboard is connected.

Grammarly has done this thing, but I do not find any way to detect hardware keyboard connections in my keyboard class.

Update :
You can get a connection via

```
let isKeyboardConnected = GCKeyboard.coalesced != nil
```

but you need to check for this method continuously

Comment: Try searching for `ios detect external keyboard` ... plenty of results to look through to find a suitable approach. Here is one result to start with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31991873/how-to-reliably-detect-if-an-external-keyboard-is-connected-on-ios-9

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want notification in App, I want to detect in keyboard extension which is UIInputViewController class